# Error in connect to website jsoup project(The method connect(String) is undefined for the type Jsoup)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

i want to fetch data from website to my android app ,so i used jsoup.

```
   Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

error in this line of my project.i use above line three time as my requirement but all the three time where  this above line is use and all three line shows error message.
Help how to remove this error ..

if anyone knows any other easy method/way to get(fetch) data from dynamic website data to android app  kindly also mention that way..

```
    public class Jsoup extends Activity{

    // URL Address
    String url = "http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html";
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate the Buttons in activity_main.xml
        Button titlebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.titlebutton);
        Button descbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.descbutton);
        Button logobutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logobutton);

        // Capture button click
        titlebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Execute Title AsyncTask
                new Title().execute();
            }
        });

        // Capture button click
        descbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Execute Description AsyncTask
                new Description().execute();
            }
        });

        // Capture button click
        logobutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Execute Logo AsyncTask
                new Logo().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    // Title AsyncTask
    private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String title;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Jsoup.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Get the html document title
                title = document.title();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set title into TextView
            TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
            txttitle.setText(title);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    // Description AsyncTask
    private class Description extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String desc;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Jsoup.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Using Elements to get the Meta data
                Elements description = document
                        .select("meta[name=description]");
                // Locate the content attribute
                desc = description.attr("content");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set description into TextView
            TextView txtdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desctxt);
            txtdesc.setText(desc);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    // Logo AsyncTask
    private class Logo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Jsoup.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Using Elements to get the class data
                Elements img = document.select("a[class=brand brand-image] img[src]");
                // Locate the src attribute
                String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
                // Download image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                // Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set downloaded image into ImageView
            ImageView logoimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
            logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: The method connect(String) is undefined for the type Jsoup

Comment: Don't post your errors as comments, as they should be part of your question. Use [edit] option and add information about error in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't name your class same way as already existing classes because compiler will connect each call of simplified name to current class, not to the class from imports. For instance

```
class String {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf("1"));
    }
}
```

will not compile because `String.valueOf` will not try to invoke `valueOf` from `java.lang.String` but from ***your class***, and since there is no such method there you are seeing error saying that such method is undefined.

So change name of your class

```
public class Jsoup extends Activity{
    ...{
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); 
    }
}
```

to something more like

```
public class JsoupActivity extends Activity{
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ...{
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); 
    }
}
```